# why the method with int parameter is considered for numerical value?

Tags: java

```
class Test {
  void m1(byte b) {
    System.out.print("byte");
  }

  void m1(short s) {
     System.out.print("short");
  }

  void m1(int i) {
     System.out.print("int");
  }

  void m1(long l) {
     System.out.print("long");
  }

  public static void main(String [] args) {
    Test test = new Test();
    test.m1(2);
  }
}
```

The output is : int. why does jvm consider the method with int parameter?

Comment: For completeness, you could add an `m1(float)` and `m1(double)` to your example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because integer literals are of type `int` in Java. You'll need an explicit cast if you want to call the other ones. (Or add a `L` suffix if you want to call the `long` version.)

See the [JLS Lexical Structure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1) §3.10.1 *Integer Literals* for the details.

Answer (score 4):

```
Data       Type          Default Value (for fields)
byte        0
short       0
int         0
long        0L
float       0.0f
double      0.0d
char       '\u0000'
String (or any object)      null
boolean false
```

So you need to explicitly to give the number as parameter to the appropriate primitive type you want

If you try giving

```
 public static void main(String [] args) {
    Test test = new Test();
    test.m1(2L);
  }
```

The output will be `long`

In case of `short` or `byte` (implicit is `int`), you will need a cast to that type

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.m1((short)2);
      }
```

Reference: [Primitive Data Types in Java](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)